# SQL- Add up all the values in a resulting column and calculate the percentage using another column in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I found it quite difficult to describe my problem in the title, but I will be more clear here. I have two tables `users_friends` and `active_users` ... here is the schema for both

```
CREATE TABLE `users_friends` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friend_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `friend_id_user_id_index` (`friend_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7967354 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `active_users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first` varchar(155) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=150948970 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I want to see the percentage of `active_users` who are following 1 person, 2 people, 3 people, etc, etc

I ran this query which gets me the number of users following X number of people

```
( SELECT count(t.total_follows) AS users_count, t.total_follows FROM ( ( SELECT count(*) total_follows, active_users.id FROM active_users INNER JOIN users_friends on users_friends.user_id = active_users.id GROUP BY active_users.id ) AS t ) GROUP BY t.total_follows ORDER BY t.total_follows )
```

Here are the results

```
users_count   total_follows
   5                   1
   3                   2
   2                   3
```

I can get the total sum of the `users_count` column by modifying the query above and summing up the `users_count` like this

```
select SUM(t1.users_count) as total_sum from ( < insert above query> ) as t1
```

but I don't know how to calculate the SUM of the `users_count` column divided by the `users_count` which would get me the desired result shown below

```
users_count    total_follows   percentage
   5                  1           50.0
   3                  2           30.0
   2                  3           20.0
```

I know I can get this column value by doing this

```
(count(t.total_follows) / 10) * 100 as percentage
```

but I can't hardcode the total sum ( 10 ) in my query. I need the query to calculate everything in 1 run. How can I modify my query to achieve this ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this isn't syntactically correct because it would be a select clause inside another select clause @urdearboy

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using a "with" statement:

```
WITH x as
( 
SELECT count(t.total_follows) AS users_count, 
t.total_follows 
FROM ( ( SELECT count(*) total_follows, active_users.id 
FROM active_users 
INNER JOIN users_friends on users_friends.user_id = active_users.id 
GROUP BY active_users.id ) AS t ) 
GROUP BY t.total_follows 
ORDER BY t.total_follows )
)

SELECT *, COUNT/(SELECT SUM(users_count) FROM x)::FLOAT percentage from x
```

Comment: This would probably work perfectly if my version of mysql supported the WITH clause : / ... thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just computing the total sum of all the columns and storing them in a variable called `@total_sum` and then using that in a second query  ... would have been nice if I could use the `WITH` statement like @Stoddard Meigs proposed, but my version of mysql doesn't support it

```
set @total_sum = (select SUM(t1.users_count) as total_sum from ( ( SELECT 
count(table1.total_follows) AS users_count, table1.total_follows FROM ( ( 
SELECT count(*) total_follows, active_users.id FROM active_users INNER JOIN 
users_friends on users_friends.user_id = active_users.id GROUP BY 
active_users.id ) AS table1 ) GROUP BY table1.total_follows ORDER BY 
table1.total_follows ) ) as t1);

( SELECT count(table1.total_follows) AS users_count, table1.total_follows, 
(count(table1.total_follows) / @total_sum) * 100 as percentage FROM ( ( SELECT 
count(*) total_follows, active_users.id FROM active_users INNER JOIN 
users_friends on users_friends.user_id = active_users.id GROUP BY 
active_users.id ) AS table1 ) GROUP BY table1.total_follows ORDER BY 
table1.total_follows )
```